# Laravel testing different code on same database

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I want to move my application from custom framework to laravel and I try to figure out how I'll provide tests on Laravel in future.

At the moment I test like this:

- I have my app in 2 folders `main` and `test`

  - `main` folder for `appexample.com` domain
  - `test` folder for `test.appexample.com` domain
- So when I want to do some changes, firstly I make it in `test` folder and check if everything works fine, then I copy with replace `test` folder to `main` folder

If I would want to use laravel, how should I do those tests correctly with laravel?

Thanks

Comment: if you are going to setup a "test" environment why not bother to setup a "test" database as well? Having the same DB for the test and live environment will only enhance murphy's law

Comment: ye the "test" database should be too, but question is more about how to correctly test code? should it be 2 laravel projects (one for production and one for test) or its possible to make with 1 laravel project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you have is not a *test* environment but a [*staging* environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/948167/1998801)...

What you would have to have is 2 Laravel apps:

- Production (`appexample.com`) should be using a production GIT tag (for example, `v1.5.3`) or at least use a production branch like `master` or `main`
- Staging (`test.exampleapp.com`) should be using a development branch like `develop` or whatever your team defined as it

You can have a look at [Laravel Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/) and [Laravel Envoyer](https://envoyer.io/).

- Forge: Allows you to manage servers, environments, deployments, PHP versions, databases (I do not recommend to have a database on the Laravel app server), and more stuff

  - Those servers can be on AWS, Digital Ocean, and more
- Envoyer: Allows you to manage deployments, environments, and more

  - The take away from Envoyer is that it will help you deploy easier to multiple servers (let's say you have a load balancer and 4 servers behind it, it will automatically deploy the same code and run deployment steps on each server, and if any fails, it just goes back without the client knowing anything happened)

---

This means you SHOULD (I would say MUST) have separate databases, one for *staging* and one for *production* (YOU NEVER RUN PHPUNIT TEST ON ANY ENVIRONMENT EXCEPT LOCAL OR DEVELOPMENT).

Also, you should "replicate" your data on staging, so staging is as similar as possible related to prouction:

- Same database version
- Same web server engine
- Same PHP version
- Etc.

If you are going to upgrade any, it is fine if staging has a newer database, web server, PHP, etc. version than production, that is the idea, test stuff there before release.